# Angular 6 cross domain POST request to .NET Web API returns 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: angular, http, asp.net-web-api, cors, rxjs

I've got an `Angular 6` app on which I'm trying to do a `POST` request to our `.NET Web API` project which is on a different local domain.

Attempting this `POST` throws the following error to console:*`POST http://localhost:9090/api/values 401 (Unauthorized)`*

Web API is running on `localhost:9090`
Angular is running on `localhost:5200`

**In .NET Web API, my CORS is enabled in `Web.config`:**

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:5200" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
```

**Angular service (supposed to log errors to the server):**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Request, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, catchError, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ErrorService {

    http: Http;

  constructor(http: Http) {

    this.http = http;
  };

  postError(argument) {
    let request = new Request({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:9090/api/values"
    });

    return this.http.request(request)
      .pipe(map(res => res.json()))
      .subscribe(
        data => console.warn(data),
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log("empty")
      );
  }
}
```

I suspect my Angular service - perhaps I'm not including necessary credentials in my headers?

One last note - when creating a new Web API project from scratch, the POST works (I haven't tried w/ my specific service, but my team mate was having the same `401` issues and creating a new Web API project worked for him).  So some setting in my `Web API` project is such that my Angular service is not meeting the security standards of the `Web API` project (?). Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you use NTLM authentication:

My first try would be including the Request option `withCredentials` like stated [here](https://angular.io/api/http/Request):

```
let request = new Request({ method: "POST", url: "http://localhost:9090/api/values", withCredentials: true});
```

I would also highly recommend to use HttpClient instead of Http and Request Classes as they are [deprecated](https://angular.io/api/http/Request).

Comment: Thank you Jon Skeet - I mean Daniel. That was a great answer - worked like a charm.